# How to remove margins in highmaps?

Tags: typescript, highcharts

I am trying to remove the left and right margin in a highmaps plot. However, it does not work even when setting them explicitly to zero like this:

```
Highcharts.mapChart("investment", {
  chart: {
    map: mapdata,
    borderWidth: 2,
    marginLeft: 0,
    marginRight: 0
  },
```

See a live demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/91kn3w37w).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts use `margin` like a CSS padding [Api](https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/chart.marginRight) between the chart and the border. You need `width` cause the default value is 100% like a standard `div`

```
  chart: {
    map: mapdata,
    borderWidth: 2,
    marginLeft: 0,
    marginRight: 0,
    width:300
  },
```

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/y30k188j5x)